# Getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException in Tomcat7

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

The program attempts to send e-mail but throws a run time **exception:AuthenticationFailedException**.I have used smtp protocol for sending the mail.I have used TLS.Below is my Mailsender class named SendMail.java

```
  package com.xxx.dashboard.mail;

  import java.util.Map;
  import java.util.Properties;
  import javax.mail.Message;
  import javax.mail.MessagingException;
  import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
  import javax.mail.Session;
  import javax.mail.Transport;
  import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
  import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
  import com.edifixio.dashboard.configuration.ConfigurationBundle;

  public class SendMail {

  public static void sendMail(String toAddresses, String subject, String url, String name, String email){

    Map<String, String> mapdata = ConfigurationBundle.getMapdata();
    final String emailId = mapdata.get("mail_id");
    final String username = mapdata.get("mail_username");
    final String password = mapdata.get("mail_password");
    final String smtpHost = mapdata.get("mail_smtp_host");
    final String smtpPort = mapdata.get("mail_smtp_port");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);


    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                                  return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                           }
                    });

       try {
              Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
              message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailId));
              message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(toAddresses));
              message.setSubject(subject);

              String text =  "<b>Hello "+name+",</b><br/><br/> Thank you for registering with WARM for monitoring of your URL."
                    + "<br/>In order to activate your account please <a href="+url+"><b>Click Here</b></a><br/><br/>"
                            + "Once you have activated your WARM account you can login to the WARM Dashboard using your Username "
                            + "<a href=\"mailto:"+email+"\">"+email+"</a>.<br/>If you are having problems with the given link, "
                                    + "please reply back to the following Email address: <a href=\"mailto:warm.xxx@gmail.com\">warm.xxx@gmail.com</a>.</br>This is a system generated mail. Please do not reply to this mail.<br/><br/>Thanks and Regards<br/>WARM Admin.";

              message.setContent(text,"text/html");
              Transport.send(message);
       } catch (MessagingException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    sendMail("sumit.ghosh@xxx.com", "Hello", "h", "Rakesh", "rakesh@gmail.com");
    System.out.println("Successfully send mail to - "+toAddresses); 
  }
}
```

When I am choosing Run as Java Application from Eclipse I am getting the following error log

```
       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 qk9sm15826619pac.16 - gsmtp
       at com.xxx.dashboard.mail.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:80)
       at com.xxx.dashboard.mail.SendMail.main(SendMail.java:87)
       Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 qk9sm15826619pac.16 - gsmtp
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
       at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
       at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
       at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
       at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
       at com.edifixio.dashboard.mail.SendMail.sendMail(SendMail.java:74)
       ... 1 more
```

I have a properties file named config.properties where I have kept the username and password,and other credentials like port no.Please find below its code:

```
mail_id=test@gmail.com
mail_username=test@gmail.com
mail_password=testxxx
mail_smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com
mail_smtp_port=587
ldap_provider_ip=192.168.15.50
ldap_port=1666
ldap_base=ou=users,ou=warm,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=in
ldap_dir_context=dc=edifixio,dc=co,dc=in
ldap_security_principal=cn=Directory Manager,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=in
ldap_security_credential=testxxx
```

Comment: pass `mail.smtp.protocol=smtps`

Comment: no its not working.I have done props.put("mail.smtp.protocol", "smtps");but it gave same exception

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well, I had to go into my gmail account settings and under Security Enable "Access for less secure apps" to fix it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Hamad, it might be short but in what way does this not answer the question?

Comment: That's worked for me.... :)
Only need to change the account permission.
Is that might be a security threat??

Answer (score 2):

I was also trying out the simple javax mail program using the google smtp server . On receiving Authentication failed messages ,I had to goto https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and turn on access for less secure apps
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to the gmail account specified in your properties file
2. Click on the circle on your top right corner -> manage your google account -> security -> Less secure app access . Turn it on
3. Go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.
4. Click on continue and logout of the gmail.
5. Test your service. Now it will establish a connection to send mails

Answer (score 0):

Try with these properties:

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms=login
mail.smtp.quitwait=false
mail.debug = false
mail.username=test@gmail.com
mail.password=test
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.protocol=smtps
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working either.I have given port no 465 this time around.Any Other solution???

Comment: With these exact properties I am using a gmail server in my java application with TLS. Try to make the debug property true and check if there is any specific error. Your exception has this link which you can check out too https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

Comment: well It worked finally.but not with port no 465 but with port no 587.I had to clear the CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sent mail without any exceptions in eclipse on Debian OS. Are you running any firewall or anti-virus software that might be interfering with the connection attempt?

Comment: problem is Solved now.There was some captcha related problem in my gmail id.